Task Scheduler Windows Server 2022
I hava a task configure in windows server 2022 excecuting every 5 min, it must check if the server if is running over the UPS battery, to do that it run a script, this script check the cmdlet Win32_Battery and so on.
the thing is that when the server goes to the UPS Battery the task I see is excecuting but the last Run Time not updated
Another thing when I run it manually it excecute the script and the Last Run Time is updated
In the tab of Task Condition I uncheck the next options in Power:
Start the task only if the computer is on AC Power
Stop if the computer switches to Battery Power

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Please create an MRE (Minimal, Reproducible Example). It should include invocation of Get-CimInstance.
